# What is the purpose of isFirstPageAfterLogin method in admin/session model?

Tags: magento

I see where this method is being used, but I'm wondering who has an authoritative answer on the matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you said you know where, but I'm going to mention it here for completeness since you didn't... hope you don't mind! :)

The flag that isFirstPageAfterLogin() checks is set in the login() method that's called during the admin login process.

It is used in the following places:

- `Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController` to store the value in the admin session so that it's still available on the first page load *after* the login form is submitted.
- `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Window` to determine whether or not to show the notices "window" that often shows after login.
- A few actions on `Mage_Adminhtml_Report_StatisticsController` in order to redirect the user to the page they should be if their login routes them to one of the report refresh actions.
- `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` uses it to redirect a user back to the dashboard if their login routes them to an action that would send a download response, which frequently can rely on filter data that may or may not be available to the controller if it come from the login.

So to recap, it's a very important flag that is used to control some behind the scenes behavior. The most important being redirecting to the correct login page and allowing for one-time notices to show upon login.

Answer (score 2):

This value is used in `Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController`, specifically the `indexAction()`, and redirects the admin user to the *start up page* defined in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Startup Page`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for!